# URI does not encode date in ISO 8601 format

Tags: java, uri, encode

Why URI does not encode date in ISO 8601 format?

```
URI uri = new URI("http", "www.home.com", "/test", "filter[>date]=2016-11-16T00:00:00+00:00", null);

Output: http://www.home.com/test?filter[%3Edate]=2016-11-16T00:00:00+00:00
```

Comment: What output did you expect and why?

Comment: I expected to see the folowing output `http://www.home.com/test?filter[%3Edate]=2016-11-16T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00` `:` and `+` should be encoded

Comment: But that doesn't happen because `:` and `+` are not illegal characters in the query string of an URI. The [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) explain exactly which characters are encoded or not.

Comment: Ok. I will use my additional encoding for that.

Comment: It seems that URI and URLEncoder have their own different illegal characters set. For [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) `:` and `+` are illegal.